# Problems mapping Hibernate entities - native query containing left join with condition

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This should be straight-forward though can't get my Hibernate entities to play nice for the following scenario with a simple two table structure:

[image: db structure]

I'm attempting to get all config names and matching config values for a given currency code (and null's where not matching).. so have written a native query to retrieve the following like so:

```
SELECT * FROM CONFIG_NAME LEFT JOIN CONFIG_VALUE ON CONFIG_NAME.ID = 
CONFIG_VALUE.CONFIG_ID AND CONFIG_VALUE.CURRENCY_CODE = '<CURRENCY_CODE>'
ORDER BY CONFIG_NAME.ID
```

This query doesn't seem to play nice with my Hibernate mapping as it appears to be essentially ignoring the CURRENCY_CODE clause in the join.

Essentially, for the following subset of data:

**CONFIG_NAME:**
[image: config name]

**CONFIG_VALUE:**
[image: config value]

There is no value defined for 'FREE_SHIPPING_ENABLED' for 'USD' so running the query above for both currency code returns as expected:

**QUERY RESULTS FOR 'CAD':**
[image: cad query]

**QUERY RESULTS FOR 'USD':**
[image: usd query]

I'm running the above query as a native query in a JpaRepository for the ConfigName entity. But what I appear to be getting is that it seems to ignore the currency_code clause in the JOIN condition. As the list of config values defined has both values for USD and CAD where they're populated. Is there an Hibernate annotation to factor this in that I'm unaware of?

It's worth bearing in mind there will only ever be **ONE** value defined for each config for a given currency - there's a unique constraint across CONFIG_VALUE.CONFIG_ID/CONFIG_VALUE.CURRENCY_CODE so potentially ConfigValue on the ConfigName entity would not need to be a map.

Mappings as are follows:

ConfigName - Entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "config")
private Set<ConfigValue> configValue;
```

ConfigValue - Entity

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="CONFIG_ID")
@Property(policy=PojomaticPolicy.NONE)
private ConfigName config;
```

Doesn't need to be strictly unidirectional either.. as I'm only concerned with the values from the ConfigName entity either being populated or null.

Think I'm missing something simple, so hope someone can help.

EDIT: Am querying using JpaRepository:

Am using JpaRepository to query:

```
@Repository
public interface ConfigNameRepository extends JpaRepository<ConfigName, Long> 
{

  static final String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM CONFIG_NAME "
  + "LEFT JOIN CONFIG_VALUE ON CONFIG_NAME.ID = CONFIG_VALUE.CONFIG_ID "
  + "AND CONFIG_VALUE.CURRENCY_CODE = ?1 ORDER BY CONFIG_NAME.ID";

  @Query(value = SQL_QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
  List<ConfigName> findConfigValuesByCurrencyCode(final String currencyCode);
}
```

Comment: Show us actual use of Hibernate. How do you query?

Comment: @Antoniossss: have updated question with JpaRepository am using with a native query.

Comment: Since it is native query, i am not sure if your relations matter here. Did you try using @Param annotation?@Param("currencyCode") String currencyCode and making same change in query? (config_value.currency_code = :currencyCode)

Comment: Thanks, but am afraid that didn't make a difference. That's probably just a stylistic change.. the query remains relatively the same as far as I know. The problem I reckon is definitely in the relationship or entities.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ouney, your JPA relations are not taken in account if you use a native query.

You declared a `SELECT *` and `List<ConfigName>` (the real sql result contains `ConfigName`+`ConfigValue`). So with this query, Hibernate fetchs all the `ConfigName`. Then, when you try to access to the set of `configValue`, it fetchs all the related `ConfigValue`.

I think this should be better/easier to use a JPQL query instead (but you need Hibernate 5.1+) :

```
SELECT n, v
FROM ConfigName n
LEFT JOIN ConfigValue v
ON v.config = n AND v.currencyCode = :currencyCode
ORDER BY n.id
```

With this method signature :

```
List<Object[]> findConfigValuesByCurrencyCode(@Param("currencyCode") String currencyCode);
```

Where the result will be :

```
o[0] // ConfigName
o[1] // ConfigValue (nullable)
```

You may want to do this prettier with a wrapper :

```
SELECT new my.package.MyWrapper(n, v)
...
```

`MyWrapper` constructor :

```
public MyWrapper(ConfigName configName, ConfigValue configValue) {
    ...
}
```

Method signature with the wrapper :

```
List<MyWrapper> findConfigValuesByCurrencyCode(@Param("currencyCode") String currencyCode);
```

**(update)**

I think in this case, your query can be :

```
SELECT n, v // or new my.package.MyWrapper(n, v)
FROM ConfigName n
LEFT JOIN n.configValue v
WITH v.currencyCode = :currencyCode
ORDER BY n.id
```

Comment: Looks good @Ludovic Guillaume. I'll give it a shot.. though not sure if I'll be easily able to upgrade Hibernate. Any way to do this pre-5? Maybe HQL or similar?

Comment: Have tried that but am getting: _Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 104 [SELECT n, v FROM ConfigName c LEFT JOIN n.configValue v ON v.currencyCode = :currencyCode ORDER BY n.id]_

Comment: Actually, the following HQL appeared to work: _SELECT n, v FROM ConfigName n LEFT JOIN n.configValue v WITH v.currencyCode = :currencyCode ORDER BY n.id_